# Decorating AA resources with POROs (plain Old Ruby Objects)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

We have bit complex logic in the admin part of our app, so they say the best way to fight the complexity is to use decorators.
I know Active Admin supports using of Draper gem for that http://activeadmin.info/docs/11-decorators.html, but I'm not sure I need it (for reasons you could read this aricle http://thepugautomatic.com/2014/03/draper/).

Thus, we decided to use POROs here. But I'm sticked with it, and can't make AA to use new "decorated" methods, they are just ignored.
Maybe I use wrong idea how the decorator should look to be used by Active Admin..

Here is the sample app to demonstrate: https://github.com/kiote/aa_plus_poro

Could someone please help me to understand, what I'm doing wrong with this kind of decorators?
Thanks!

Comment: `decorate_with ArticlePresenter` how is `decorate_with` meant to work, I can't see any code that would allow that to work.  If you read the article you link they do `@article = Article.first
    @article_presenter = ArticlePresenter.new(@article)`

Comment: @japed, thank you for suggestion. Active Admin is the one who handles ```decorate_with```: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/dsl.rb#L166

Also they apply this decorator to resource: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/resource.rb#L146

Comment: Thanks, I don't use ActiveAdmin, looking at the comment in that though `Assuming decorator_class.to_s will return the name of the class allows
      # us to handle a string or a class.` maybe you need to implement `.to_s` method on your presenter.  If not have you restarted your app since creating your presenter so it knows it's there?

Comment: for now default ```.to_s``` returns ```"::ArticlePresenter"``` hope that's what Active Admin expect to. Anyway I have no idea what should it return instead.


And, huh, I restart the app all the time)

Comment: What is the actual error that you're getting? It would really help if you also linked directly to the affected files in your repo instead of just to the root, forcing us to search for relevant content.

Comment: I got the answer from Active Admin author Timo Schilling: 

"ActiveAdmin don’t work well with Poro decorators at the moment.

Please open a issue"

So discussion moved to https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/3600, but thanks for your help anyway!